# Replacing terms in multiple files using Perl

Tags: sh

I would like to replace some values in input files named " i_f.xyz " using perl, where i goes from 1 to 19.

In my files, I want to change a "6" into a "C".

To do so I tried

```
perl -pi -e 's/6/C/g' ${i}_f.xyz
```

, and some other combinations but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me please ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Where do you set `i`? You tagged this Perl, but the problem is with the shell script executing Perl. What shell are you suing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the placeholder variable. Use `for`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=19; i++)); do
    perl -pi -e 's/6/C/g' "${i}_f.xyz"
done
```

Edit: [replace `seq` with bash built-in](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#line-259)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler (no need any loop):

```
perl -i -pe 's/6/C/g' 1[0-9]_f.xyz [0-9]_f.xyz
```

(from `1_f.xyz` to `19_f.xyz`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer guys.

At the end I found a solution to do it with:

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in *_f.xyz
do

perl -pi -e 's/6/C/g' *_f.xyz
perl -pi -e 's/1/H/g' *_f.xyz

done
```

But now I've got other approachs also ! I'm new in bash script, programming language and other computer science things, so thanks ! :)

Comment: The shell will expand the `*` placeholder into many filenames for the perl command, and perl will iterate over them, so the outer `for` loop is completely pointless here. The whole script can be replaced with one line: `perl -pi -e 's/6/C/g; s/1/H/g;' *_f.xyz`